# Using XML::Saxon::XSLT2 in Perl Errors

Tags: java, perl, xslt-2.0, perl-module

I am currently trying to use the XSLT2 module in a Perl script.  I am currently getting an error when running the script due to including this module.  The main error statement is:

```
Transformer.java:1: error: package net.sf.saxon.s9api does not exist
```

I'm assuming this means that when I installed XML::Saxon::XSLT2, it didn't know where the Saxon jar file was.  I have it on my computer but I'm not sure how to get Inline::Java or XSLT2 to recognize that it's there or install it or do whatever I have to do.  Sorry, I don't really know too much about Java and classpaths and what not so I'm sort of in the black on this issue.

Answer (score 0):

> This module implements XSLT 1.0 and 2.0 using Saxon 9.x via
>   Inline::Java.
>
> It expects Saxon to be installed in either:
>
> ```
> '/usr/share/java/saxon9he.jar'
> ```
>
> or:
>
> ```
> '/usr/local/share/java/saxon9he.jar'
> ```
>
> Future versions should be more flexible. The saxon9he.jar file can be
>   found at http://saxon.sourceforge.net/ - just dowload the latest Java
>   release of Saxon-HE 9.x, open the Zip archive, extract saxon9he.jar
>   and save it to one of the two directories above.
>
> [http://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Saxon::XSLT2](http://metacpan.org/pod/XML%3a%3aSaxon%3a%3aXSLT2)

So just cd to the directory where you currently have the saxon jar file and type:

```
$ mv saxon9he.jar /usr/local/share/java/
```

Comment: So just adding the directory that I have it saved to worked.  That's fine for what I'm doing right now, but I want to create a standalone executable.  Usually creating executables from perl isn't to bad, but I don't know how I'm going to specify the correct path when it goes into the executable.  Is there anyway to specify a path that will let me just keep the jar file in the same path as the module file.

Comment: You cross posted this at perlmonks, so thanks for wasting my time.